# Benzene Identification in a liquid?

Tags: aromatic-compounds

how can we identify the presence of benzene in a liquid? How to find the percentage of benzene in a liquid? Are there any feasible tests that could be done to find it?

Honestly, all we have is a chemistry lab with the bare minimum necessities.

Comment: Do you have access to a GC-MS?

Comment: Maybe GC is enough !

Comment: I have no access to a GC -MS. Is there any way to do this without them?

Comment: What do you have access to? and what are the liquids to be analysed? and what are approximate concentrations? Benzene has distinct uv, ir-Raman, nmr spectra, can be separated by gc or lc and possibly by azeotropic distillation. Learn about these various methods and see if what you have is appropriate. Then get some professional help perhaps starting with some chemistry courses.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, there are no simple and cheap tests for it without instrumental analysis. Naive ideas like *Add this and a color forms if the substance is present* work for very limited number of cases.

Probably the easiest way is to contact some environmental lab or water treatment company lab as an external private customer, if they could do such an analysis for you. But it may cost up to (hopefully lower) hundreds of dollars. The best if you have a friend working there, the price could be addressed by alternative payment.

I worked in such a lab 15 years ago and trace analysis of aromatic hydrocarbons in water were done routinely.